# subquery error in group by when converting from MySQL to PostgresSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm converting my database from MySQL to PostgresSQL, and I have this query which tries to sord the products by the cheapest price and the most popular in a given location. It works fine in MySQL, but in Postgres I'm running into problems with this query :

```
SELECT products.product_id,
       suppliers.supplier_id,
       product_code.desc_fa,
       products.name_fa,
       MIN(product_supplier.price) AS price,
       SUM(COALESCE(orders.quantity, 0)) AS n_orders
FROM products
JOIN product_code ON product_code.code_id = products.code_id
JOIN product_supplier ON product_supplier.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = product_supplier.supplier_id
JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = product_tags.tag_id
JOIN product_crop ON product_crop.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN crops ON crops.crops_id = product_crop.crop_id
LEFT JOIN orders
    ON orders.product_id = products.product_id and orders.crop_id = product_crop.crop_id
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = orders.user_id and user.location_id = 883
WHERE crops.crops_id = 1
  AND product_supplier.quantity >= 3
  AND tags.tag = 'علف کش'
GROUP BY products.name_fa 
ORDER BY n_orders DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

It gives me this error :

```
column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Any suggestions to how to work around this error ?

**UPDATE** :
According to the answers i was able to make it work by using this query:

```
WITH tem_1 AS (SELECT product_id, MIN(price) AS price FROM product_supplier GROUP BY product_id) ,
     tem_2 AS (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS n_orders FROM orders Group by product_id)
SELECT products.product_id, suppliers.supplier_id, product_code.desc_fa, products.name_fa, tem_1.price, 
products.telegraph, suppliers.location_id, COALESCE(tem_2.n_orders,0) AS quant FROM products
INNER JOIN product_supplier ON product_supplier.product_id = products.product_id
INNER JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = product_supplier.supplier_id
INNER JOIN product_code ON product_code.code_id = products.code_id
INNER JOIN product_crop ON product_crop.product_id = products.product_id
INNER JOIN crops ON crops.crops_id = product_crop.crop_id
INNER JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.product_id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = product_tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN tem_1 ON tem_1.price = product_supplier.price AND tem_1.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN tem_2 ON tem_2.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE crops.crops_id = 1 AND product_supplier.quantity >= 3 AND tags.tag = 'علف کش'
ORDER BY quant DESC
LIMIT 10;;
```

But since i'm fairly new to SQL, I wanted to know if my code is correct or is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: What don't you understand about that error?

Comment: That query does not work fine on MySQL, it gives a more or less random result. (And will raise an error on newer versions, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Any non-constant field that does not have an an aggregate function needs to be in the "group by."  I know not all DMBS require this, but it baffles me that that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

When you use aggregate function (as SUM, MIN and others) the other columns in your field list without aggregate function must be included in GROUP BY clause.

These fields:

```
products.product_id,
suppliers.supplier_id,
product_code.desc_fa,
products.name_fa
```

must be in `GROUP BY`.

Instead your `GROUP BY` clause has only the following field:

```
products.name_fa
```

You must add the other missing 3 fields

In `MySql` this error has turned off by default, so your query works fine, but in other DBMS you are in an error case.

You can see [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) how set MySql environment about the `GROUP BY` behaviour

Comment: I have different suppliers selling the same product at different price points, also some products are more popular than others in a given location. For example we have product A and product B, and product A is more popular that product B based on how many has already been sold and for product A we have 3 suppliers. I want my query to show the cheapest seller for product A in that location first, then the cheapest seller for product B. But if i add GROUP BY suppliers.supplier_id, it show all 3 suppliers for that product , not one! So how should I achieve my desired result ?

Comment: @PouriaMazandarani: Please post your data set and your wished result set. So, for your aim, you can use a subquery, but if you post data set and structure, I can help you

Comment: i was able to get the results i was looking for, i posted the new code the question, is this new query correct?